# Build thrift dll for use in Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: dll, build, windows-phone-7, thrift

Pretty straight forward question: How do I build a [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) dll for use in a Windows Phone 7 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written out step-by-step instructions on making the Thrift runtime work on WP7, and on changing the C# generator to generator WP7 compatible bindings:

https://damian.fyi/2011/01/11/generating-silverlight-windows-phone-compatible-thrift-proxies/

At some point I want to submit the changes back to the Apache project - when I have some time ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean a Thrift client as a server wouldn't make a lot of sense on a phone.

Regardless, a quick scan of the [white paper](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/static/thrift-20070401.pdf) makes me think you can't as it requires use of sockets and these are not available to developers in WP7.

Beyond that it would be a case of writing an implementation of the interface specified by Thrift.
I know that is a very vague answer but it's a very vague question.

Comment: I mean a Thrift client offcourse :) I know there is an adaption of Thrift that are wrapped over HTTP, but I'm not sure it's been ported to C#. Maybe the only solution is to port it myself...

Comment: @greve yes, you're going to port it if no one else has. I assumed your original question was basically "how do I port Thrift to run on WP7?" which is very vague.